# DynamoDB how to search for a list of values

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a DynamoDB instance with a partition key and sort key. Let's say that they are organisation (hash key) and employee id (sort key).

I want to retrieve all employees who's ids are in a list. They all work for the same organisation but they are not *all* of the employees of that organisation.

In SQL I'd do something like:

```
select * from table where organisation_id = 'org' and employee_id in [list of ids]
```

There does not seem to be an equivalent in DynamoDB.

My choices seem to be:
1) Iterate over all employee IDs using a Query OR
2) Use BatchGetItems and provide organisation_id:employee_id for all items

The first seems like it will be slower as it involves multiple requests while the second is a single request but may consume more RCUs.

Which of these is preferred solution to this problem? Or am I missing a better third way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would iterate your list using GetItem, adding each employee found to a collection. This approach isn't slow - DynamoDB is designed specifically for getting lots of items fast using their keys.

There is no need to use Query as you have both the partition key and range key. You would only use a Query if say you wanted all employees of one organisation.

If your list is particularly large you could use BatchGetItem, which will create multiple parallel threads and therefore reduce latency. You won't find much a difference though unless you have a lot of items to get.

By the way, DynamoDB does have an 'IN' operator but your can't use it on KeyConditions.

Comment: Thanks for the response and the clarification of IN.  The number of items I need to fetch will be somewhere sub 100 (from millions).  Am I right in thinking that the network latency on 100 GetItem calls would be significant compared to a single BatchGetItem?